# regexp get content type boundary

Tags: php, regex

How to get the boundary in this header?

```
$header = 'Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;'."\n"
.'    boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01D16F24CC6015F600AB1926COL004?MC5F18.ho"';

preg_match('/Content-Type:(.*)boundary="([^\"]+)"/i', $header, $match);
print_r($match);
```

output

```
9B095B5ADSN=_01D16F24CC6015F600AB1926COL004?MC5F18.ho
```

Comment: Use the `s` modifier. Demo: https://eval.in/535591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match('/boundary="(.*?)"/i', $header, $match);
```

or

```
preg_match('/Content-Type:(.*)\n*\s*boundary="([^\"]+)"/i', $header, $match);
```

Output

```
9B095B5ADSN=_01D16F24CC6015F600AB1926COL004?MC5F18.ho
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/boundary=(.*)/', $header, $match);
```